# R convert nx1 array to mx4 matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large array containing 100,000 elements. I want to convert it to a four-column matrix with col1 containing values 1:25000, col2 containing 25001:50000, etc.

Is the best way to do this a loop? My best attempt so far does not execute, so would like to know the best way.

```
for (i in 1:25000){
mat[i,1] <- arr[i]
mat[i,2] <- arr[i+25000]
mat[i,3] <- arr[i+50000]
mat[i,4] <- arr[i+75000]
   }
```

I also suspect there is a better way, so if you know a better method, would love to hear it.

As an example:

```
16
48
27
80
59
20
79
24
57
7
95
11
58
91
2
29
53
4
83
47
```

will become...

```
16  20  7   2
48  79  95  29
27  24  11  53
80  57  58  4
59  7   91  83
```

Comment: In your title you say you want to convert a vector to a matrix, then in the text, it becomes an array you want to convert to a matrix.

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ reproducible example. Arguments `ncol` and `byrow` in `matrix` seem relevant here.

Comment: Maybe just `dim(arr) <- NULL ; matrix(arr, ncol = 4)` ? Though I still don't understand if you just have a vector or an array? As your "array" doesn't look like an array at all

Comment: this solves my problem. was hoping there would be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(x <- 1:20)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

dim(x) <- c(5, 4)
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    2    7   12   17
# [3,]    3    8   13   18
# [4,]    4    9   14   19
# [5,]    5   10   15   20
```